# when i add content to image i couldnt click the link in image but if i delete the content:""; its working but then hover is not working

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to add `a href` to my photo, but i added some `hover` effect, and now `href` is not working. How can i fix that without using javacript?

```
    echo "
        
        <div class = 'image' >
        
  <div class= 'haberr'>   <h1>".$row['name']."</h1>".$row['author']."</div>
   <a href = 'https://www.alba.com.tc/".$row['linkname']."'>
   <img src = '".$row['photo']."' alt='alba' width='500' height='320' alt = ''>
   </a>
   
  </div>
  
 
  ";}
```

```css
 

   .image{
    
background-position: center center;
pointer-events: none;
    display:flex;
width:33.3%;
height:320px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 5px;

 
}
.image:after{
 pointer-events: all;
    object-fit: cover;
     content: "  ";
    transition: opacity .4s ease;
    display: block;
    will-change: opacity;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 0,#000 99%,#000 100%);
    opacity: .7;
position: absolute;
}
.image:hover:after{
content:"";
    transition: opacity .4s ease;  
    will-change: opacity;
    z-index: 1;
  box-shadow:linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 0,#000 99%,#000 100%);
    opacity: .9;
object-fit: cover;
    position:absolute;

}
```

Comment: why twice `.image:after`?

Comment: ı accidnetly send the wrong code. I fix that now.

Comment: delete `content: "";` in `image:hover:after` an give it a try

Comment: the hovers depend on content